Since mapping islower semicontinous then there exist converging sequence
I am considering the proof from paper "Existence Of Financial Equilibria In A Multiperiod Stochastic Economy".
Under the assumption:
The preference correspondence ${P}_i$, from $Q_i \in \prod_{i \in \mathcal{I}} X_i$ to $X_i$, is lower semicontinuous, i.e., ${P}_i$ is a lower semicontinuous correspondence, and the set ${P}_i(x^*)$ is convex.
So we know that $P_i$ is convex and lower semicontinous. Then we define enlarged preferences
$$
\hat{P}_i(x^*) := \bigcup_{\mathbf{x}_i \in {P}_i(x^*)} ( x_i^*, \mathbf{x}_i \big] = \{ x_i^* + t(\mathbf{x}_i - x_i^*) \mid t \in \, (0, 1], \, \mathbf{x}_i \in {P}_i(x^*) \}.
$$
However it is not the most important part there.
Let $ \text{Consider a sequence } (x^{*n})_n \subset \prod_{i \in \mathcal{I}} X_i.$
The question is the sentence:
Since ${P}_i$ is lower semicontinuous, there exists a sequence $(x_i^n)$ converging to $x_i$ such that $x_i^n \in {P}_i(x^{*n})$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
How we can obtain such a conclusion for this sequence. Is there any reference to a theorem or can the to got this conclusion be expanded?
